# How to display only specific data from the entire list storage on python django server (rest framework)

Tags: python, django, database, django-rest-framework, request

I have to display (as in topic title) only specific data from the list which is storage on server (PYTHON/DJANGO/REST_FRAMEWORK).

F.e. I want to choose data which has planted on the server with 'id=1', but I always get back all items. Can you explain how to correct this?

'urls' file (project level) :

```
# URL routes - known as endpoints API
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('devices/', include('efota.api.urls')),
]
```

'urls' file (subordinate folder) :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.DeviceList.as_view()),
    url('<int:pk>/', views.DeviceDetail.as_view()),
]
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

'views' file :

```
class DeviceList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()  
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer 

class DeviceDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Device.objects.all()      
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
```

'serializers' file:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    # the 'fields' controls which database attributes are available
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'id_token',
            'current_firmware',
            'carrier_code',
            'model_name',
            'owner',
        )
        read_only_fields = ['id']


    def get_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        return obj.get_api_url(request=request)
```

'models' file:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='owner', 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='user')
    id_token = models.CharField(max_length=1000, 
            verbose_name='id_token')
    current_firmware = models.CharField(max_length=41, 
           verbose_name='current_firmware')
    carrier_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, 
           verbose_name='carrier_code')
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=10, 
           verbose_name='model_name')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created', )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name
```

'admin' file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Device

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Device)
```

Comment: did you try **`your_host/devices/1/`** ?

Comment: yup, exactly and always i've got the same result

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing old-style URL and new-style path syntax in your urls.py. The `url()` function takes a regex, and `r''` matches *every* URL, while `<int:pk>/` would only match that *literal string*. Use `path` instead.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.DeviceList.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DeviceDetail.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter result returned by ListAPIView you can modify its get_queryset method as follows.

```
class DeviceDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Device.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```